# Visual Studio Code Debugger can't see arrays data

Tags: javascript, debugging, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm using Ionic and I'm trying the debugger from Visual Studio Code, but I cant see array's data.
The only thing that shows is [Object] and I can't click on it to expand the data inside of it. If I try to debug the App with "GapDebug" I can see it perfectly.

Is there any option I need to change or I need any plugin??

If I can't see array's data, then, what kind of debugger should I use for Ionic apps? I don't really like GapDebug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could stringify your array:

```
console.log('DEBUG: ' + JSON.stringify(myArray));
```